# Facebook API: Unable to Authorize myself

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

I am working on my first Fb App. Just for testing purpose I went to my Account Settings and removed the app, now I can't access my own App and getting error:

> API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not
>   owned by the application Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by
>   the application.

Using following code in PHP for Authorization:

```
$auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     }
   $access_token = $data["oauth_token"];
   $user = intval($data["user_id"]);
```

One thing I would add that if I access redirect_uri directly on browser then it shows dialog box to authorize my app but when I access my App URL on browser then it gives error and redirects to following URL

```
https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=363045713726227&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2F363045713726227%2F&response_type=none&display=page&perms=user_photos&auth_referral=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the value of $my_url it's impossible to say, however, you've probably got $my_url set to a value that is outside of the "owned" domain that you have set in the developer application control panel.

The settings you are looking for are ***App Domain:*** ***Site URL:*** and ***Canvas URL:***, please note that whilest Site URL: looks like it shouldn't be applicable, it actually is, in that you need a Site URL: set for the App Domain: to take affect.

Comment: cool, that's it then, it needs to be the same as in the Canvas URL: field, so probably http://localhost/fb/photos/.

Comment: already using same URL, I am just not being able to see Authorization Dialog

Comment: SO removed what I wanted to type there, it autolinked the url, it should be `http://localhost/fb/photos/`

Answer (score 1):

In the domain URL, you must specify some url that you own. It can be edited from the Application Settings page. Else, for testing, you can use some facebook URL like `...&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/home.php`

Comment: I had not made any changes in App Settings, just unauthorized myself after going in Settings->Applications and removed my own App. Since this it started giving error. I wanted to test AuthDialog feature so I did this